# Is there a way to get the factory instance of a class?

Tags: objective-c, ios4, objective-c-runtime

I would like to use the Objective-C runtime to call `objc_msgSend()` on a factory object and I need to build its arguments.  I would like to specify its first argument using the factory instance as a compiler would.  Is there a way to obtain the factory instance?

Comment: What do you mean by a factory instance? Compilers don't create instances (except for `NSString`s). And please provide the context. With contexts, it becomes easier to provide an answer.

Comment: Compilers do not create instances, you are right.  The run time does.  I am asking about the runtime.  I found my answer: objc_getClass()

Comment: For confused Objective-C people reading this entry: his "factory instance" is the "class object" in our parlance.

Comment: I apologize for using Stepstone's "factory" parlance.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

objc_getClass() is the function that provides the factory object instance as my question heading asks.

Comment: Which language background did you come from? Note that in the Objective-C community people usually use the term "class object" instead of "factory object instance."

Comment: I grew up speaking English.  I also was taught that asking about someone's background in a condescending manner was rude.  I believe that Stepstone used "Class Object" originally too, but I simply forgot.  Regardless of my glaring shortcoming the nomenclature is far from consistent.

Answer (score -1):

Within an implementation of a class `MyClass`, the superclass can be obtained by

```
Class superClass=[MyClass superclass];
```

You can put that into `objc_super` structure. Note that the compiler doesn't make any instance of a class... the compiler uses a class object, which is an instance of the metaclass. For more information read [this post at Hamster Emporium](http://www.sealiesoftware.com/blog/archive/2009/04/14/objc_explain_Classes_and_metaclasses.html).